# Initializing lots of instances

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures

I would like to know if there are better ways to initialize a large collection of same-type instances. This is not a problem only limited to Swift, but I am using Swift in this case.

Take, for example, a large list of **API endpoints**. Suppose I have 100 endpoints in this API and each of them share some common functionality, such as headers, parameter lists, parsing formats, etc... albeit with different values for each of these "options".

I could think of a few different ways to express 100 endpoints:

1. Create a resource file with all of the values and read them in from the file on app launch. The problem with this is that it becomes stringly typed and there is potential for typos and/or lots of copy/paste key values. This would include **plist files, json files, sqlite tables, csv files**, etc. It centralizes and condenses the data, but it doesn't seem maintenance friendly or swiftly. Furthermore, it seems like resource files are harder to obfuscate should the details be somewhat private.
2. Create a giant enum-ish function with all of the API endpoint instance **initialization code blobbed all in the same area/function/file**. This would be equivalent of doing a giant switch statement or making a collection literal with all the instantiation happening in one spot. The advantage here is that it can be strongly typed and it is also contained to one area, similar to what a resource file would do. However, it will be a BIG file with lots of scrolling. Maybe too big?
3. Create a **separate file/module/instance/subtype for each** endpoint and, more or less, hardcode computed properties inside the instance. This would be maybe creating an extension and/or subclass for each endpoint and putting them in a separate swift file. This limits the visual scope for each endpoint, but it also just turns your project files into the blob of data instead.

I'm wondering if there are philosophical arguments for either of these options. Or, are there other options I have not thought of. Is it preference? Are there best practices when initializing a large collection of what seems like a bunch of complex literals?

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of this static data, or machine-generated classes, consider the advice in [WWDC 2016's Optimizing App Startup Time](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/406/). It's a great talk. The loader has to initialize and fix up all your static object instances and classes; if you have a lot, your app load time will be adversely affected.

For static data, one piece of advice is to use Swift, which you've already done, as Swift knows to defer the instantiations until run time.

Swift doesn't help with mass-produced classes; though you can switch to structs instead.

Even ignoring the startup time issue, I'd err on the side of being data driven. Option 1. Less code to maintain. IMHO There's nothing wrong with stringly typed here, this code is unlikely to change much; adding endpoints will be trivial. It's cool to see new function when you didn't even write new code!